# how to grant role acces to specific schema

Tags: oracle, permissions, schema, role, sql-grant

I am new to Oracle and i am struggling with the permissions. I created some tables with user called ADMIN on a specific tablespace. The tables are in the schema ADMIN now. I want access this tables from another user called TESTUSER which is in a role called TEST.

Is there a way to grant this role called TEST access to the schema ADMIN? Or a way to grant access to the user for this schema? I aslo want that the ADMIN tables show up in the sqldeveloper under the TEST user.

I already used some commands to try this out but it doesnt work. Eg.

```
GRANT SELECT on ADMIN.TABLE1 to TEST
```

What do I have to do?

Comment: did you try to connect as user(schema) ADMIN and execute the commend "GRANT SELECT on TABLE1 to TEST" ? what did you get ? what did you get when you tried to access TABLE1 ?

Comment: ok got it. seems that i made something wrong with the query first. is there a way to the grant the privilege to a role too?

Comment: Isn't TEST the role ? did you try "GRANT TEST TO TESTUSER" ?

Comment: i want to grant the role called TESTROLE where TEST is a member of to select tables from ADMIN schema.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming:
TEST, ADMIN are users
ADMIN is the owner of table TABLE1
TESTROLE is a role

Connect to the schema ADMIN then run command:

```
GRANT SELECT on TABLE1 to TESTROLE;
```

Then run the command:

```
GRANT TESTROLE TO TEST;
```

connect as TEST user and check:

```
SELECT * FROM ADMIN.TABLE1;
```